# Cannot read preporties of undefined (reading 'register') at chartjs-plugin-annotationLine.js срочно нужна помощь

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Всем здравствуйте!Мне нужна помощь!

```
    const annotationLinePlugin = {
  renderAnnotationLine: function(chartInstance, line) {
      let datasetMeta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(line.datasetIndex);
      let context = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
      let datasetModel = datasetMeta.data[line.dataIndex]._model;

      const xBarCenter = datasetModel.x
      const barWidth = datasetModel.width;
      const xStart = xBarCenter - (barWidth / 2) - 4;
      const xEnd = xBarCenter + (barWidth / 2) + 4;

      const yAxisID = datasetMeta.yAxisID;
      const yCoordinate = chartInstance.scales[yAxisID].getPixelForValue(line.yCoordinate);

      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = line.color;
      context.lineWidth = line.width;
      context.moveTo(xStart, yCoordinate);
      context.lineTo(xEnd, yCoordinate);
      context.stroke();


      if (typeof line.label !== typeof undefined) {
          context.textAlign = 'center';
          context.fillStyle = line.color;
          context.fillText(line.label, yCoordinate, xEnd + 7);
      }
  },

  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {
      if (chart.data.datasets.length < 1) {
          return;
      }
      if (chart.config.lines) {
          chart.config.lines.map(line => {
              this.renderAnnotationLine(chart, line);
          });
      }
  }
};


 Chart.plugins.register(annotationLinePlugin);
```

В браузере выдаёт ошибку :

```
Uncaught TypeError : 
Cannot read preporties of undefined (reading 'register') 
at chartjs-plugin-annotationLine.js:42:15
```

Comment: И что находится в файле chartjs-plugin-annotationLine.js в 42 строке на 15 позиции? В дебагере не пробовали смотреть?

Comment: В 42 строке находится Chart.plugins.register(annotationLinePlugin)

Answer (score 0):

Описание ошибки говорит Вам, что у объекта Chart свойство plugins undefined, что означает либо его полное отсутствие, либо что его значение не было проинициализированно. Вы смотрили на доступные свойства объекта Chart в дебагере?

На [официальном сайте библиотеки Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/) размещенна информация о [миграции на версию 3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html), [согласно которой](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#removed-from-chart):

> `Chart.plugins` был заменен на `Chart.registry`. Значения плагина по умолчанию теперь находятся в формате `Chart.defaults.plugins[id]`

Comment: Странно... Думал, что комментарий писал, а оно как-то здесь ответом оказалось. У меня с головой что-то или изменил кто?

Comment: chartjs-plugin-annotationLine.js правильно работает на chartjs 2,а вот на chart js 3 не хочет работать.

Comment: Хотите,я вам скину полный архив с этими файлами?

Comment: @АндрейНикитин поправил "ответ"

Comment: Вообщем заменил Chart.plugins.register на Chart.register,появилась ошибка в браузере : Uncaught Error : class doen not have id.

Comment: Мне срочно нужен ваш ответ!)

Comment: @АндрейНикитин если у Вас изменился код, то правьте Ваш вопрос. Если появляется ошибка, то где она появляется, в какой строке, что находится в этой строке, что показывает дебагер? Имеется ли в руководстве по миграции что-то на эту тему? Пробовали Вы подключить плагин используя [примеры](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)? Плагин поддерживает 3 версию? Есть документация к плагину? Поймите, что хорошо заданный вопрос - это уже половина ответа.